# Can I force a dynamic library to link to a specific dynamic library dependency?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, static-linking, autotools, dynamic-linking

I'm building an dynamic library, `libfoo.so`, which depends on `libcrypto.so`.

Within my autotools Makefile.am file, I have a line like this:

```
libfoo_la_LIBADD += -L${OPENSSL_DIR}/lib -lcrypto
```

where `$OPENSSL_DIR` defaults to `/usr` but can be overridden by passing `--with-openssl-dir=/whatever`.

How can I ensure that an executable using `libfoo.so` uses `${OPENSSL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.so` (only) *without* the person building or running the executable having to use `rpath` or fiddle with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

As things stand, I can build `libfoo` and pass `--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl-special` and it builds fine. But when I run `ldd libfoo.so`, it just points to the `libcrypto.so` in `/usr/lib`.

The only solution I can think of is statically linking `libcrypto.a` into `libfoo.so`. Is there any other approach possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You've struck out the most likely possibilities already.  How would you characterize an acceptable solution other than "read my mind"?

Comment: Also, dynamic linking / loading details vary from platform to platform.  In what particular platform are you interested?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm ok with an answer that says "well... that's just not possible". I'm not familiar enough with the subject area to know if I'm missing something else. W.r.t. platforms, the project in question currently builds on Linux and MacOS, so some portability would be good. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Details of runtime dynamic linking vary from platform to platform.  The Autotools can insulate you from that to an extent, but if you care about the details, which apparently you do, then it probably is not adequate to allow the Autotools to choose for you.

With that said, however, you seem to be ruling out just about *all* possibilities:

- The most reliable way to ensure that at runtime you get the specific implementation you linked against at build time is to link statically.  But you say you don't want that.
- If you instead use dynamic libraries then you rely on the dynamic linker to associate a library implementation with your executable at run time. In that case, there are two general choices for how you can direct the DL to a specific library implementation:

1. **Via information stored in the program / library binary**.  You are using terminology that suggests an ELF-based system, and for ELF shared objects, it is the `RPATH` and / or `RUNPATH` that convey information about where to look for required libraries.  There is no path information associated with individual library requirements; they are identified by SONAME only.  But you say you don't want to use `RPATH`<sup>*</sup>, and so I suppose not `RUNPATH` either.
2. **Via static or dynamic configuration of the dynamic linker**.  This is where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` comes in, but you say you don't want to use that.  The dynamic linker typically also has a configuration file or files, such as `/etc/ld.so.conf`. There you can specify library directories to search, and, with a bit of care, the order to search them.

Possibly, then, you can cause your desired library implementation to be linked to your application by updating the dynamic linker's configuration files to cause it to search the wanted path first.  This will affect the whole system, however, and it's brittle.

Alternatively, depending on details of the nature of the dependency, you could give your wanted version of libcrypto a distinct SONAME.  Effectively, that would make it a different object (*e.g.* libdjcrypto) as far as the static and dynamic linkers are concerned. But that is risky, because if your library has both direct and indirect dependencies on libcrypto, or if a program using your library depends on libcrypto via another path, then you'll end up at run time (dynamically) linking both libraries, and possibly even using functions from both, depending on the origin of each call.

*Note well* that the above issue should be a concern for you if you link your library statically, too.  If that leaves any indirect dynamic dependencies on `libcrypto` in your library, or any dynamic dependencies from other sources in programs using your library, then you will end up with multiple versions of libcrypto in use at the same time.

**Bottom line**

For an *executable*, the best options are either (1) all-static linkage or (2) (for ELF) `RPATH` / `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` / `RUNPATH`, ensuring that all components require the target library via the same `SONAME`.  I tend to like providing a wrapper script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so that its effect is narrowly scoped.

For a reusable *library*, "don't do that" is probably the best alternative.  The high potential for ending up with programs simultaneously using two different versions of the other library (libcrypto in your case) makes all available options unattractive.  Unless, of course, you're ok with multiple library versions being used by the same program, in which case static linkage and `RPATH` / `RUNPATH` (but not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) are your best available alternatives.

---

<sup>*</sup>Note that at least some versions of `libtool` have a habit of adding RPATH entries whether you ask for them or not -- something to watch out for.  You may need to patch the libtool scripts installed in your project to avoid that.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I was looking for someone to explain the extent of my options, which you've done very clearly. Thank you.

Comment: *I tend to like providing a wrapper script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so that that its effect is narrowly scoped.*  Funny, I like using `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` in the executable itself because `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will propagate to child processes.  Of course, that means I have to package the executable with the proper shared objects, which can also cause problems.

Comment: That is a valid consideration, @AndrewHenle.  By "so that its effect is narrowly scoped" I meant relative to using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your default shell configuration, not relative to using `RPATH` and / or `RUNPATH`, which is indeed even more narrowly scoped.  I have apparently betrayed my general bias against using `RPATH` and (to a lesser extent) `RUNPATH`.  But all of these tools have their purposes and plausible use cases.